# Adjust default UI of Input Date on Android Browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Some of my users do not know that the year on the date picker can be selected. I just wanted to add an arrow next to the year just like the following image.

I guess currently there is no way to do it, but just wanted to make sure so I ask for helps.

[image]